# comparing the variables and their values between two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames with same kind of data, now i want to check for all the columns in both data frames have same kind of text in all columns in both data frames .

so for example the column name "sales executives" in both data frames have exact name "Micheal klay" in both data frames but if there is any spelling error or extra space i want to show it as not matching.

I have tried below approach and its working for small database but because my data is very big, data having approx 10 - 40 millions or records so its showing error
do we have any solution or any other approach to do that

**cannot allocate vector of size 3.2GB**

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(MAN=c(6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8),MANi=c("OD","NY","CA","CA","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL","NY","OD","CA","OD"),
                  nune=c("akas","mani","juna","mau","nuh","kil","kman","nuha","huna","kman","nuha","huna","mani"),
                  klay=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2),emial=c("dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd","xyz","abc","dd"),Pass=c("Low","High","Low","Low","High","Low","High","High","Low","High","High","High","Low"),fri=c("KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP","TGA","KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK"),
                  mkl=c("m","f","m","m","f","m","m","f","m","m","f","m","m"),kin=c("Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Rec","Sent","Rec"),munc=c("Car","Bus","Truk","Cyl","Bus","Car","Bus","Bus","Bus","Car","Car","Cyl","Car"),
                  lone=c("Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man"),wond=c("tko","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kent","bho","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kilt"))

df2 <- data.frame(MAN=c(6,6,4,6,8,6,8,4,4,6,6,8,8,8,6),MANi=c("OD","NY","CA","CA","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL","ny","OD","CA","OD","NY","OL"),
                  nune=c("akas","mani","juna","mau","nuh","kil","kman","nuha","huna","kman","nuha","huna","mani","juna","mau"),
                  klay=c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1),emial=c("dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC","dd","xyz","ABC"),Pass=c("Low","High","Low","Low","High","Low","High","High","Low","High","High","High","Low","High","High"),fri=c("KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP","TGA","KKK","USA","IND","SRI","PAK","CHI","JYP"),
                  mkl=c("male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male","male","female","male"),kin=c("Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec","Rec","Sent","Rec","Sent","Rec"),munc=c("Car","Bus","Truk","Cyl","Bus","Car","Bus","Bus","Bus","Car","Car","Cyl","Car","Bus","Bus"),
                  lone=c("Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","Sr","jun","sr","jun","man","man","jr","man"),wond=c("tko","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kent","bho","bho","kilt","kent","bho","kilt","kent","bho"))

df1_long <- df1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.double, as.character) %>% distinct() %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Names", values_to = "options") %>%   
  arrange(Names, options)

df2_long <- df2 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.double, as.character) %>% distinct() %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Names", values_to = "options") %>%   
  arrange(Names, options)

T1 <- df1_long %>% 
  full_join(df2_long, by=c("Names", "options"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
  distinct(Names.x, options.x, Names.y, options.y) %>% 
  arrange(Names.x, Names.y,  options.x, options.y) %>% 
  mutate(
    consistant_names = !is.na(Names.x) & !is.na(Names.y),
    consistant_options = !is.na(options.x) & !is.na(options.y)
  )
```

the output required like below

[image]

below are inconsistency between data bases

[image]

Comment: Your join is far too broad, as it joins every instance of one value (e.g. every "male") to every other instance of that value in the same column. I suspect you should be joining before you pivot, since you are trying to join based on one (or multiple) specific columns.

Comment: If the tables have the same rows you might try the `waldo` package to compare differences between data frames.

Comment: @JonSpring I treid this waldo but that also didn't worked, what changes i need to make in my code ...??